# Failed to compile opengauss

Tags: open-gauss

I failed to compile opengauss. The error messages are showed following.

```
[ 97%] Built target ecpg_compat
make[2]: *** [src/bin/pg_basebackup/gs_basebackup] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/bin/pg_basebackup/CMakeFiles/gs_basebackup.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 97%] Built target pq_ce
CMakeFiles/gs_ctl.dir/backup.cpp.o: In function `BaseBackup(char const*, unsigned int)':
/home/data/database/openGauss-server/src/bin/pg_ctl/backup.cpp:1430: undefined reference to `GetMotCheckpointDir(char const*)'
/home/data/database/openGauss-server/src/bin/pg_ctl/backup.cpp:1431: undefined reference to `FetchMotCheckpoint(char const*, pg_conn*, char const*, bool, char, int)'
CMakeFiles/gs_ctl.dir/pg_ctl.cpp.o: In function `do_incremental_build(unsigned int)':
/home/data/database/openGauss-server/src/bin/pg_ctl/pg_ctl.cpp:4457: undefined reference to `GetMotCheckpointDir(char const*)'
/home/data/database/openGauss-server/src/bin/pg_ctl/pg_ctl.cpp:4458: undefined reference to `FetchMotCheckpoint(char const*, pg_conn*, char const*, bool, char, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/bin/pg_ctl/gs_ctl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/bin/pg_ctl/CMakeFiles/gs_ctl.dir/all] Error 2
```

I downloaded the source code of openGauss-server from https://github.com/opengauss-mirror/openGauss-server and the third party library from https://github.com/opengauss-mirror/openGauss-third_party and compiled according to this instruction https://github.com/opengauss-mirror/openGauss-server/blob/master/README.en.md
Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is one build option named as "enable_mot". You can disable it and pass building.

Meanwhile, I'd like to suggest using configure/make to complete the build as readme shows.

Answer (score 0):

from the error 'error: ld returned 1 exit status', it seems you are missing the third party libs. you can use the compiled third party and make sure you config it in you ENV.